# How can a const pointer refering to mutable data can be 'converted back' to non-const pointer?

Tags: c++, architecture, constants

I'm refactoring a compiler front-end, and facing a problem of const variable, which are non reversible to their non-const counterpart.

Context is the following : I have an abstract syntax tree (AST) and a symbol table which contains symbols, and I want to compute types of the ast nodes and symbols in the symbol table.
I will refer the type computation part as 'Subsystem'.

Constraints are the following :

- My AST is a complex structure, so I would like to avoid iterating through all the node each time it is possible.
- The Subsystem is built following functional paradigm, so it wont directly alterate anything (neither AST or Symbol table), but only compute a type and eventually a symbol by using the symbol table. Its parameters arethe current AST node which type has to be computed and the Symbol table .
- When the Subsystem computing is done, I want to refer the returned symbol as a non-const pointer.

Here is a (really simplified) version of what I am talking about :

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <map>

// For readability / understandability only
using Type = int;
using Symbol = int;

struct TypeSymbol {
    Type t;
    const Symbol* s;
};

TypeSymbol ComputeTypeSymbolInSubsystem(const std::map<std::string, int>& data) {

    return { 123, &data.at("bar") };
}

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, Symbol> symbols = { {"test", 0 } , { "foo", 51 }, { "bar", 63 }, {"", 2 } };

    auto typeSymbol = ComputeTypeSymbolInSubsystem(symbols);

    // Obvious compilation error, even if "s" is still refering to a mutable memory zone (the symbols variable)
    *typeSymbol.s = 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Which results in the following compilation error under gcc 9.2.0:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:25:19: error: assignment of read-only location '* typeSymbol.TypeSymbol::s'
   25 |     *typeSymbol.s = 1;
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
```

Problem is : as Symbol table and AST are passed "const" to the Subsystem, it is now impossible to get a const pointer from the returned TypeSymbol 's' value.

How can I get back to a non-const pointer in this context ? I thought about using const_cast, but it usually implies a design flaw, isn't it ?

Comment: `const_cast` isn't what implies a design flaw, but rather treating read-only data as mutable.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between a const-pointer-to-nonconst-data vs a nonconst-pointer-to-const-data?  You are dealing with the latter, which is why your code fails to compile.  You are trying to modify data via a pointer-to-const-data, meaning the pointer can't be used for writing. If you know the memory being pointed at is writable, then yes you can `const_cast` the pointer to allow writing to the data. Otherwise, you need to re-think your use of `const`

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes I do, that compile fails is just a way to show a ultra simplified version of my actual system design problem. I know the error, but not the proper solution, except with this const_cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of `const_cast` is an option in your case.

```
*const_cast<Symbol*>(typeSymbol.s) = 1;
```

but remember that it can be dangerous some times.

If the original object was created as a `const` object, you run the risk of undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I'm 100% sure about my original object being mutable, because only my class SymbolTable is allowed to build Symbol (with a private friend constructor). I'm not a big fan of const_cast but if it is the only viable solution I have to accept it !

Comment: @Scorbutics, the other option is to remove `const` from the declaration of `s` -- `Symbol* s;`

Comment: @R Sahu , sadly if I do that, I also have to remove const everywhere, because the compile error would become : `main.cpp: In function 'TypeSymbol ComputeTypeSymbolInSubsystem(const std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&)':
main.cpp:14:30: error: invalid conversion from 'const mapped_type*' {aka 'const int*'} to 'Symbol*' {aka 'int*'} [-fpermissive]
   14 |     return TypeSymbol { 123, &data.at("bar") };
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                              |
      |                              const mapped_type* {aka const int*}`

Comment: @Scorbutics If you leave `const` in place where needed, you would just have to `const_cast` when assigning a pointer to `s`, rather than `const_cast`'ing when writing to memory via `s`, eg: `TypeSymbol ComputeTypeSymbolInSubsystem(const std::map<std::string, int>& data) { return { 123, &const_cast<Symbol&>(data.at("bar")) }; }` You definitely should not declare `s` as pointing to `const` memory if you plan on writing to memory via `s`. But really, why is `ComputeTypeSymbolInSubsystem()` taking a reference to a `const map` if the data is meant to be mutable in the first place?

Comment: Because in practice, ComputeTypeSymbolInSubsystem is a multi files system (around 10 files) which has in total around 1000 lines if code. And I would like to be sure I cannot modify anything into it to keep a functional way of doing things and avoid having a lot of places where I edit the Symbol Table. const_cast when assigning the pointer may also be a good idea. I will think about it !